# MIME type in Response Header coming as application/json for css and js files

Tags: http, jboss, mime-types, jsf-2.2

During migration to jboss-eap-7.0.8,
MIME type in Response Header coming as application/json for css and js files.
Due to this css is not getting applied on my login page.

Basically in Response Header Content-Type = application/json
expected Content-Type = text/css(in case of *.css file) or text/javascript(in case of *.js file)

My application is using jsf 2.2

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is **_NOT_** JBoss 7... it is based on Wildfly 10 iirc https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269470

Comment: and can you create a [mcve]? Just to be sure the right things are investigated?

Comment: Yeah, seems really strange JBoss would be doing that, if you create a minimal example as Kukeltje suggested and put it up on GIT we might be able to help troubleshoot.